# Google indexing mostly JSON and Javascript files of my next.js website

Tags: javascript, next.js, google-search-console, google-index

I have a problem with Google indexing of Next.js (we use SSR). For SEO is important to index .HTML files. But Googlebot index mostly JSON and Javascript files. For example, yesterday he made 540 requests to my website ( 215 Javascript, 84 JSON, and only 30 HTML).  So question is, how to give Googlebot to index mostly HTML files. Because of this problem, I can't index all pages of my websites. Googlebot has a limited number of requests to the site and they go to Javascript or JSON files. My website is [skillcombo.com](https://skillcombo.com).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question and is off-topic on Stack Overflow. It's more likely to get an answer on https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a good sitemap.xml and provide that to the Google Search Console for your website.

Comment: I have already done it , but it doesn't help to solve my problem.

Comment: ok, then you also have considered to create a specific robots.txt?

Comment: Of course, I'm not good at programming, but I'm good at SEO)